# text formatting in the app.?

Tags: android, text, formatting, edit

very simple question.
or am i being an idiot.
basically i made an app with text in the .xml like this (in a list):

```
-name
-email
-phone
-venue
-date
-etc
```

instead in the app it comes out like this

> name address phone county etc

is it just me or is this simple ive looked and search google but i cant find anything relevant to my situation

- what should i be using if im doing it wrong

  - do i need to create a another textview eveytime i have anew line?

thanks so muchhhh

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Main" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:text="Name *
Phone *

Email *

Type of Event

Date of Event (if known)

What would you like to know more about?

Message:
"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your xml please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your TextView to this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:text="Name *\n
    Phone *\n
    Email *\n
    Type of Event\n
    Date of Event (if known)\n
    What would you like to know more about?\n
    Message:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

`\n` is the `newline` character. Use it if you want line breaks.

Comment: orentiation doesnt seem to do anything